# c# Parse json Date?

Tags: c#, json, datetime

I get a json date from a webservice that i need to parse manualy and the date looks like this: 
"Fri, 06 Nov 2009 00:00:00 -0800"

How would i parse this into a datetime object?

I guess i should use DateTime.ParseExact but what do i feed into it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use DateTime.Parse.  I verified it works for this string.

Comment: ok now im embarresed! thanks alot i didnt think it would be that easy!

Answer (score 2):

`var date = DateTime.Parse("Fri, 06 Nov 2009 00:00:00 -0800");` works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I ran this code and it worked fine:

```
string date = "Fri, 06 Nov 2009 00:00:00 -0800";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out: [Converting String to DateTime C#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

// parse JSON formatted date to javascript date object

```
var date = new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.substr(6)));
```

// format display date (e.g. 04/10/2012)

THEN

```
var displayDate = $.datepicker.formatDate("mm/dd/yy", date);
```

from http://blog.degree.no/bloggere/