# JSON date from tweeter to C# format

Tags: c#, json, json.net, date-format

How to format a JSON date obtained from twitter to a C# DateTime ?
Here is the format of the date I receive :

```
"Tue, 19 Feb 2013 13:06:17 +0000"
```

Can I do it with JSON.NET ?

Comment: What happens when you do `DateTime.Parse("Tue, 19 Feb 2013 13:06:17 +0000")`?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551662/c-sharp-parse-json-date

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved with use of `DateTime.ParseExact`

-> http://blog.kevinyu.org/2012/07/handling-json-in-net.html

**Link Update:** the linked blog post is offline. It cached copy can still be referenced [via the Way Back Machine Internet Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20170310125132/http://blog.kevinyu.org/2012/07/handling-json-in-net.html).

The common .NET code copied from the blog post is:

```
public const string Const_TwitterDateTemplate = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +ffff yyyy";

DateTime createdAt = DateTime.ParseExact((string)jo["created_at"], 
Const_TwitterDateTemplate, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

where

- variable `jo` is a JSON object representing the `created_at` date property, but effectively the Twitter date string goes into this parameter

Comment: Thanks for link, next time please post date format here, parsing twitter date is a common task.

Comment: The date format string in this example is incorrect. ffff is the format specifier for ten thousandths of a second, and the +0000 in a Twitter date indicates the hours and minutes offset from UTC. The correct format string is "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy". [Custom Date and Time Format Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 10):

Part of code from flow's answer.

```
public const string Const_TwitterDateTemplate = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss +ffff yyyy";

DateTime createdAt = DateTime.ParseExact((string)jo["created_at"], Const_TwitterDateTemplate, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 7):

The answers above that use the ffff format specifier seem to return the correct result, but technically this is wrong. ffff is the format specifier for ten thousandths of a second, and the +0000 in a Twitter date indicates the hours and minutes offset from UTC. See the format below:

```
string twitterTime = "Wed Feb 22 15:49:01 +0000 2017";
string twitterTimeformat = "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(twitterTime, twitterTimeformat,
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
Console.WriteLine(dateTime);
```

Result: 2/22/2017 3:49:01 PM

You can edit the DateTimeStyles enumeration to return the local time instead of UTC if desired.

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

[DateTimeStyles Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's DateTimeOffset not DateTime. Following should work.

```
DateTimeOffset parsed = DateTimeOffset.Parse("Tue, 19 Feb 2013 13:06:17 +0000");
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed a PowerShell variant of these answers and the following worked for me.

```bsh
PS> $Created_At = 'Fri Jun 05 18:15:48 +0000 2020'
PS> [datetime]::ParseExact($Created_At,'ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy',(Get-Culture))

Friday, June 5, 2020 1:15:48 PM
```