# Why won't this string be converted to DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

2/22/2012 3:30:00

Surely that is an acceptable format to be converted to DateTime using Convert.ToDateTime()?

Comment: Can you post you code so i can have a look

Comment: What errors are you getting? I just tried this in Visual C# 2010 Express and it works. Could it be an issue somewhere else? Please post the code that is giving a problem.

Comment: Yes, it surely is. http://ideone.com/DsXGZ Can you post your code, and also your current locale? (And somehow I knew @JonSkeet would be answering SkonJeet's question about this particular subject...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would personally avoid using `Convert.ToDateTime`. I generally prefer<sup>1</sup> to use `DateTime.TryParseExact`, specifying the culture and format string you expect - assuming you *have* an expected format, of course. If you don't, you have to ask yourself bigger questions.

For example:

```
DateTime value;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None,
                           out value))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Parsed to {0}", value);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Failed to parse");
}
```

That's a slightly odd format to start with - normally a 24-hour format would include a leading 0 for the hour, and a 12-hour format would include an am/pm designator.

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, I *prefer* to use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com), but that's a different matter...

Comment: Judging by the poster's name, I'm sure he'll be excited to receive an answer from you.

Comment: So `Jon Skeet` answered `Skon Jeet`'s question!

Comment: Haha indeed, the right answer aswell once again. Thanks Skon, errmm Jon.

Answer (score 4):

> Surely that is an acceptable format to be converted to DateTime using Convert.ToDateTime()?

Surely not. That would be true for some locales but for example I have a `fr-FR` locale and this is an invalid date. There are no 22 months in the year. Make sure you specify the format when parsing the date. You could use the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method for this.

Comment: Alternatively to specifying the format, one could overcome the culture mismatch by specifing the culture using the `Convert.ToDateTime(string, IFormatProvider)` overload.

Answer (score 1):

If you got the Information about Year, Month, etc. separately as Integers I would rather use the Constructor of DateTime.

```
DateTime myDateTime  = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
```

Usually nothing can go wrong with this...

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to if you supply an IFormatProvider which specifies the culture (e.g. en-US in that case).

```
var date = Convert.ToDateTime("2/22/2012 3:30:00", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to use Convert.ToDateTime() which will help you to understand it : 
[Convert.ToDateTime example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/9xk1h71t.aspx)

Or You can try by following this example : 
[Convert String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me:

```
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime("2/22/2012 3:30:00");
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortDateString());
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToShortTimeString());
```

Of course I am not paying attention to localization like Darin suggests