# Formatting a string to datetime

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime, type-conversion

I have a string in the format:

YYYY-MM-DDDDTHH:MM:SS

This comes from a data feed that I need to import into a SQL Server database so we can do proper reporting off it (sort data by date and time if necessary).

I was going to just split this and manually build the data/time using the parts of the string, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this? (Maybe there's an obscure date formatting function I can call that I'm not aware of?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to DateTime C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use **[`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx#Y1600)** for this,

Example

```
DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-09-24", "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

sp in your case the format should be

```
YYYY-MM-DDDDTHH:MM:SS
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx).