# Specified string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

How to parse string "3/14/2013 2:01:18 PM" (not "03/14/2013 02:01:18 PM"!) to DateTime format?

Comment: In what language specifically & what have you tried?

Comment: Java: `new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");`

Comment: 1)C#; 2) I have some dates in different formats. How I can to parse it to datetime format with universal way?

Comment: Questions about parsing or formatting dates are one of the most frequently asked questions on StackOverflow. Every day, several people ask similar questions. Search and you'll most likely find a useful answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to DateTime C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Answer (score 2):

In c# you can use `DateTime.ParseExact` method:

```
var value = DateTime.ParseExact("3/14/2013 2:01:18 PM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.Parse` method in c#.Like

```
DateTime dtime = DateTime.Parse("3/14/2013 2:01:18 PM");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here is a list that could help you understand what are the different ways to format Date time in **C#**
Take a look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Hope this helps