# date conversion error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime

I am developing windows application.

In that i have date in the string format as>> `fileDate="15/03/2013"`

I want it to be get converted into date format as my database field is `datetime`.

I used following things for it>>

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fileDate, "yyyyy-DD-MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(fileDate);
```

Both of these methods proved failure giving me error>>

```
String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

What can be mistake?

Is there another technique to do that?

Comment: Try removing HH:ss from the above code.

Comment: nope still error is same

Comment: nope..following all answers are working [As they states one and the same thing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give the date format according to the date string you have to [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx). You can see more on [Custom DateTime format - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

*Change*

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss"
```

*To*

```
"dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Your code would be

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fileDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Date separator is `/` not `-` !

Comment: @Adil There is one problem>> my fileDate has value "15/03/2013" and dt [after conversion] is getting me to value as > 1/15/2013 12:03:00 AM. What can be the issue?

Comment: It gives 15/03/2013 12:00:00 AM, make sure you use the correct format string i.e. "dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: @PakkPuneriPorag You must use capital `"MM"` or `"M"` for _months_, not `"mm"` or `"m"` which mean _minutes_. The `3` has become minutes in your example.

Answer (score 6):

```
 string fileDate = "15/03/2013";
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fileDate, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: There is one problem>> my fileDate has value "15/03/2013" and dt [after conversion] is getting me to value as > 1/15/2013 12:03:00 AM. What can be the issue?

Comment: Change dd/mm/yyyy by dd/MM/yyyy. mm (in lower case) is the format string for minutes, not for months.

Answer (score 2):

You should do this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fileDate, "dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You must pass in the string for the format (`"dd/MM/yyyy"`) in the same style that you pass in the string `fileDate`.

Answer (score 2):

u may try with this
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse("ur_dateString")

Comment: Yeah it got worked but, There is one problem>> my fileDate has value "15/03/2013" and dt [after conversion] is getting me to value as > 1/15/2013 12:03:00 AM. What can be the issue?

Comment: The order in the original question is `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, not `"MM/dd/yyyy"`. And the `SimpleDateFormat` type is for Java, I think, not C#.

Answer (score 1):

In your current code you are using format `"yyyyy-DD-MM"` which is wrong since date part require lower case `d` not upper case `D`. , Also for year part you are specifying 5 `y`s, it should be 4, like `yyyy`, the order according to your date string should be: `"dd/MM/yyyy"`. To be on the safe side you can even use `"d/M/yyyy"`, which would work for single digit or double digit day/month.

So your code should be:

```
string fileDate="15/03/2013";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fileDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can see more on [Custom DateTime format - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Comment: There is one problem>> my fileDate has value "15/03/2013" and dt [after conversion] is getting me to value as > 1/15/2013 12:03:00 AM. What can be the issue?

Comment: @PakkPuneriPorag, this seems pretty weird, are you certain that your fileDate has the above string, also make sure you are not doing `DateTime.Parse` like in the question.

Comment: By mistake i used mm instead of MM

Comment: `mm` is for minutes, whereas `MM` is for month.

Comment: Yeah, i came to know that.Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

It's because string "15/03/2013" cannot really be parsed as DateTime with format string "yyyy-MM-dd HH:ss".

Comment: i refered this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net that why i put that