# Convert APRIL, 03/2013 string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have date in string format:

```
APRIL, 03/2013
```

How to convert to date object in C#

Comment: [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), you just have to figure out the exact format string (shouldn't be difficult given the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)).

Comment: Oops, wrong link. Anyway, this is a duplicate question of many others. Show what you have tried, your code, what your code does and what you expect it to do.

Comment: Marking to reopen as the linked question is for a different language. Can then be re-closed linked to a better question (eg: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net?rq=1)

Comment: @JonEgerton It looks like five separate people will be needed to close it. It won't let me do it now.

Comment: @JonEgerton: Even if the other question also answers the question how to convert a string to `DateTime` it's not the best ducplicate since it wouldn't help to convert this string: `APRIL, 03/2013`

Comment: @TimSchmelter: True, although the answer with most votes (by CMS) does cover `ParseExact` - its not unreasonable that it might be figured out from there.

Comment: @JonEgerton: I don't think so. `ParseExact` doesn't help to find the way to the correct format string for this exotic date-format, the cultureinfo issue or date-separator issue(`/`). You need to study a lot of sites to find the answer. Or simply use the one below ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("APRIL, 03/2013", "MMMM, dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

I have used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`(similar to english but culture independent) to enforce the `/` separator in the format and to ensure that it works in any culture.

Note that `/` has a special meaning in format strings. It means: replace me with the current culture's date separator. 
See: [the "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator).

[**Custom Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)