# Convert invalid string to DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

My input strings are of the format:

```
string a = "201101..";
string b = "199008..";
string c = "20110202";
```

How do I convert them to a date format of `yyyymmdd`?

I know I can use DateTime.TryParse() on the 3rd type.

Here's what I have:

```
string tempdate = a;
DateTime actualdate;
char[] charsToTrim = { '.' };
tempdate = tempdate.TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
if (DateTime.TryParse(tempdate, out actualdate))
{
}
```

Comment: 201101 doesn't match yyyymmdd, it has no days

Comment: What are the expected results for the 1st and 2nd input?

Comment: One solution may be to parse out what you know you have.  So if you know you have six characters and are expecting 8 in yyyyMMdd, you can say that the first six are yyyyMM. Then your year string is p.SubString(0, 4) and your Month string is p.SubString(3, 2) I think.  This is an off the cuff comment answer just to get you thinking and may not be accurate.

Comment: You'll probably end up having to implement your own parser.

Comment: [Garbage in, garbage out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) - if strings are invalid than you can simply use fixed invalid date as result. Also your sample seem to be values with fixed field size which should be handled with `Substring` and  `int.Parse` as @ToddRichardson suggested.

Comment: Thats how the value is stored in the database.. the date is unknown. I decided to add the dates as 01.            string p ="201101..";
   string tempdate;
   string format = "yyyymmdd";
   char[] charsToTrim = { '.' };
    tempdate = p.TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
   DateTime actualdate;
   tempdate +="01";
     actualdate=DateTime.ParseExact(tempdate,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass multiple formats with `DateTime.TryParseExact`

```
List<string> strDates = new List<string>
{
    "201101..",
    "199008..",
    "20110202",
};
string[] possibleFormats = new[] { "yyyyMM", "yyyydd", "yyyyMd" }; 
                                                     //single M and d to parse
                                                    //both single and double digit
                                                    //Month or Day



DateTime dt; 

foreach(string str in strDates)
{
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str.Trim('.'), 
                            possibleFormats, 
                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                            DateTimeStyles.None, 
                            out dt))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dt);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid date");
    }
}
```

The above would give you the output:

```
01/01/2011 12:00:00 AM
01/08/1990 12:00:00 AM
02/02/2011 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: I think i have it:         string p ="201101..";
   string tempdate;
   string format = "yyyymmdd";
   char[] charsToTrim = { '.' };
    tempdate = p.TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
   DateTime actualdate;
   tempdate +="01";
     actualdate=DateTime.ParseExact(tempdate,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: @sam, you don't need string concatenation, also use `MM` for month, lower case `mm` is for minutes.

Comment: Got it. But what if i need to display the date as yyyyMMdd?

Comment: @sam, just do `Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));`

Comment: private string FormattedDate(string p)
        {
            string[] possibleFormats = new[] { "yyyyMM", "yyyyMMdd", "yyyyMM'..'" };
            DateTime dt;
            char[] charsToTrim = {'.'};
            if (p != null)
            {
               DateTime.TryParseExact(p.Trim(charsToTrim), possibleFormats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
               p = dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            }

            return p ;
        }

Comment: @sam, it looks fine, You can change `p.Trim(charsToTrim)` to `p.Trim('.')` if you have just one character to trim.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`DateTime.TryParseExtract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method to specify the format of your dateTime object and it will try to convert for you, for sample:

```
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(tempdate, "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out actualdate))
{
  // conversion ok
  // use the actualdate object
}
```

Comment: It should probably be "yyyyMMdd" as the second parameter to match the question.

Answer (score 2):

Small addendum to [Habib's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255439):

```
string[] possibleFormats = new[] { "yyyyMMdd", "yyyyMM'..'" };
                                                      ↑↑↑↑
DateTime result;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("201310..", possibleFormats, null, 0, out result))
{
    // result == {01/10/2013 00:00:00}
}
```

That is, you can have the two dots in the expected format string and don't need to strip them off first.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at DateTime.ParseExact. I think it could be usefull.
And take a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something alone these lines will help:

```
private DateTime GetDateTime(string tempDate)
{
    DateTime actualdate;
    if (tempDate.Contains('.'))
    {
       DateTime.TryParseExact(tempdate.SubString(0,6), "yyyymm", out actualdate)
    }
    else 
    {
        DateTime.TryParseExact(tempdate, "yyyymmdd", out actualdate)
    }

    return actualdate;
}
```