# In C#, how can I convert a string time (formatted as HH:mm) into a DateTime variable?

Tags: c#, string, datetime, time

I have a string that represents a time formatted as "HH:mm",  say for example "8:15" (assuming the time is in 24 hour format).  In C#, How can I convert that into a `DateTime` instance where the date is today's date  and the time is 8:15 AM?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to DateTime C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Comment: @NahumLitvin, that question is about converting both a date and a time into a `DateTime`. This one only concerns times.

Comment: Keep in mind that this could be problematic if the resulting time is ambiguous or invalid due to a daylight savings change.

Comment: @Sam The "crux" of the question is the same.

Comment: @Sam please turn back your programmer hat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string ds = "8:15";
string[] parts = ds.Split(new[] { ':' });
DateTime dt = new DateTime(
                   DateTime.Now.Year,
                   DateTime.Now.Month,
                   DateTime.Now.Day,
                   Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]), 
                   Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]));
```

Comment: The value of `DateTime.Now` could potentially change in between calls to it. It's probably better to store the value in a variable. Also, you can use `DateTime.Today` to simplify some of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
 DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.Date.ToString() + " " + yourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       string time ="8:15";            
       DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy ") + time);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably parse the time using `TimeSpan.ParseExact` and then add it to today's date by 
using `DateTime.Add`.

Given that your time is in a variable like this:

```
var timeText = "8:15";
```

Parse the time like this:

```
var time = TimeSpan.ParseExact(timeText, "h:mm", /*todo*/);
```

Fill the last argument depending on your requirements.

Then add it to today's date:

```
DateTime.Today.Add(time);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming situation for current date:

```
    string time ="8:15";
    var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("{0} {1}",
             DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),time));
```

If you have a valid date in string then, you can use. Also you can use DateTime.TryParse() to check for a valid date.

```
 var date ="01/01/2014";
  var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(String.Format("{0} {1}",
                 date,time));
```

You will get output

```
01/06/2014 08:15:00
```