# How to get correct timestamp in C#

Tags: c#, timestamp

I would like to get valid timestamp in my application so I wrote:

```
public static String GetTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
}
//  ...later on in the code
String timeStamp = GetTimestamp(new DateTime());
Console.WriteLine(timeStamp);
```

output:

```
000101010000000000
```

I wanted something like:

```
20140112180244
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: `var timestamp = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff")`

Answer (score 262, accepted):

Your mistake is using `new DateTime()`, which returns January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 instead of current date and time. The correct syntax to get current date and time is [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so change this:

```
String timeStamp = GetTimestamp(new DateTime());
```

to this:

```
String timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: What is the other way around? from timestamp to datetime

Comment: @DanielV see here: [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/919244/1905949).

Comment: `double timestamp = 1498122000;

            DateTime fecha = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc).AddSeconds(timestamp);`

extracted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/250400/1257607)

Answer (score 107):

```
var Timestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Comment: Requires NET 4.6.

Comment: This was the answer for me, but I used `ToUnixTimeMilliseconds()`

Comment: How about static way `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds()` ?

Answer (score 42):

```
var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToFileTime();

//output: 132260149842749745
```

This is an alternative way to individuate distinct transactions. It's not unix time, but windows filetime.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tofiletime?view=netframework-4.8):

```
A Windows file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100- 
nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 
A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).
```

Comment: It would help if you added some explanation as to why your code answer is better than the others so other users will understand why to use you solution to this problem. Code only answers are not so helpful without an explanation.

Comment: Helps me to get easily a timestamp style to invalidate cache. +1

Comment: Great answer! This was a stitch in time saving nine on something I was struggling with. I owe you much gratitude!

Answer (score 10):

For **UTC**:

```
string unixTimestamp = Convert.ToString((int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
```

For local **system**:

```
string unixTimestamp = Convert.ToString((int)DateTime.Now.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(TIME.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

"TIME" is the DateTime object that you would like to get the unix timestamp for.

Comment: Use long intead of Int32

Answer (score 3):

```
internal static string UnixToDate(int Timestamp, string ConvertFormat)
{
    DateTime ConvertedUnixTime = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(Timestamp).DateTime;
    return ConvertedUnixTime.ToString(ConvertFormat);
}

int Timestamp = (int)DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
```

Usage:

```
UnixToDate(1607013172, "HH:mm:ss"); // Output 16:32:52
Timestamp; // Output 1607013172
```