# Correct timestamp

Tags: c#, google-maps, datetime

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219797/how-to-get-correct-timestamp-in-c-sharp) to get proper timestamp.

Before that, i've found this link with static timestamp :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=44.5406%2C-87.5011&timestamp=1374868635&sensor=false
```

When i make request to google api, i'm changing only lat/lon. 
I want to say that this timestamp :

> timestamp=1374868635

not looks like first timestamp. Does not look like DateTime.

I want to ask what is the best solution to get timestamp to make calls to google api (see the first link i mention).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try following : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249760/how-to-convert-a-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think google maps api is probably using a [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). [Here](http://www.unixtimestamp.com) you've got a converter to play. You can use this code to get it:

```
Int32 timestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

BTW, the [question you are linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21219797/how-to-get-correct-timestamp-in-c-sharp) has nothing to do with Unix Timestamp,it's just `Now` formatted.

Answer (score 1):

Google API uses Unix Timestamp

> timestamp specifies the desired time as seconds since midnight,
>   January 1, 1970 UTC. The Google Maps Time Zone API uses the timestamp
>   to determine whether or not Daylight Savings should be applied. Times
>   before 1970 can be expressed as negative values.
>   source: [Google API Timezone](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/intro)

Check [www.epochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com)

To convert current DateTime to Unix Timestamp, use (requires .NET 4.6):

```
long unixTimestamp = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

[System.DateTimeOffset.ToUnixTimeSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetimeoffset.tounixtimeseconds(v=vs.110).aspx)