# Having problems with a datetime string

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this method which shall return the day of the week (Wed):

```
protected string GetDayOfWeek(string dateTimeString)
{
    DateTime result = DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString);
    string dayOfWeek = Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), result.DayOfWeek);

    return dayOfWeek;    
}
```

I have a breakpoint on the line **DateTime result** to check the incoming string which gives:

> "Wed, 12 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT"

The above method is giving me error:

> "FormatException not handled by the user code" String not recognised
>   as a valid dateTime.

What am I doing wrong? I cannot pick it up.

Comment: With a little search, I found this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/919276/1439453 Check if this is what you want. And if not, I sure there is a lot of "convert string to dateTime" topic and solutions.

Comment: You probably want to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with an appropriate [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DateTime.Parse(string) uses the conventions of the current culture. So my guess is that "Wed, 12 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT" is not a valid date in your current culture.

You could try:

```
DateTime.Parse(dateTimeString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat)
```

That should tell the parser to be culture independent.

Comment: You got it right! The problem is the the current culture. Thanks a lot. Your answer lead to success.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the method [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and provide an exact format string for your input. In your case the call shall look like:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed, 12 Mar 2014 00:00:00 GMT", "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please show me how you would modify the above code. If instead of parse I use ParseExact, does not compile.

Comment: @Nullbyte ParseExtract accepts 3 overloads. That's why it's not compiling in your code. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

And compare with `DayOfWeek`class.

Answer (score 0):

There's two things going on here:

1. Parse a string into a DateTime
2. Get the DayOfWeek from the provided DateTime

As Tor-Erik suggests you can use DateTime.Parse with the invariant culture to get a DateTime.

```
DateTime.Parse(
    dateTimeString,
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat)
```

Then as Hevilávio Soares suggests you should use the built in functions of the DateTime object to obtain the Day of the week.

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
```

It's better to separate the concerns and to reuse existing functionality than to write your own.