# How to Convert string to date in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

i have string format of date looks like `"04/16/2014 19:10"`, i want to convert it to DateTime.

i tried, below codes, but it didn't work. i got error like "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

How to convert to datetime

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(DateTimeString);

DateTime dt = System.Convert.ToDateTime(DateTimeString);
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net

Comment: But my date format is like "04/16/2014" the link which you have given has 2009-05-08 format date

Comment: Wow - how hard can it be to grasp the concept explained in the linked question?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is [Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as you are using it, will take into account the current culture of the machine which means (depending on where you are) that date could be interpreted differently.

Whenever you are parsing *specific* dates you should use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that way you leave no room for ambiguity on how the date should be interpreted (regardless of culture)

```
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("04/16/2014 19:10", "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // date was parsed correctly, use `dt`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) and specify the format yourself:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("04/16/2014 19:10", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```