# c# add date parameter with format dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert string into DateTime object with format dd/mm/yyyy without time. but it comes with time. And also month changed to 01. The following is my coding.

```
  dateString = "4/11/2014"
  DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"d/mm/yyyy",null);
                Debug.WriteLine("date:" + date);
```

output is 4/01/2014 12:03:00 AM

If you have any idea, I appreciate very much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting String to DateTime C#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-string-to-datetime-c-net)

Comment: I'm really suprised your parsing operation will succeed. What is your `CurrentCulture`? What do you want as an output?

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime` doesn't have a format. `Strings` have formats. You need to convert your datetime to string in the format you want:

```
Debug.WriteLine("date:" + date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues in your code. Format string is missing. `mm` represents minutes instead you must use `MM` for month. Also the object `DateTime` hasn't any representation it is just `DateTime`. You should make you own representation itself. For example:

```
var dateString = "04/11/2014";
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"dd/MM/yyyy",null);
Debug.WriteLine("date: " + date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use date.date which will output the date part of the DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution.

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,"dd/MM/yyyy",null).Date;

.Date shows only date without time.

Thank you guys for reply.

Comment: I suggest you to read my answer more accurately, particularly about representation.

Comment: You are plagiarising Hamlet's answer