# Convert formatted date in string to datetime c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, type-conversion

I have date in string format as following

```
Tue Jun 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I want to convert it to `DateTime` in c#.

I am getting this date from telerik datepicker using javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your string has [UTC offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), I would parse it to `DateTimeOffset` instead. And there is no way to parse your `GMT` and `(India Standard Time)` parts without using literal string delimiter. Remember, neither `DateTime` nor `DateTimeOffset` are timezone *aware*. `DateTimeOffset` is little bit better at least since this knows about a UTC instant and an offset from that.

```
var s = "Tue Jun 30 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
DateTimeOffset dto;
if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(s, "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(India Standard Time)'", 
                                 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                 DateTimeStyles.None, out dto))

{
     Console.WriteLine(dto);
}
```

Now you have a `DateTimeOffset` as `{30.06.2015 00:00:00 +05:30}`

As an alternative (and better option), [Nodatime](http://nodatime.org/) has [`ZonedDateTime` structure](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/api/html/T_NodaTime_ZonedDateTime.htm) which is;

> A `LocalDateTime` **in a specific time zone** and with a particular offset
>   to distinguish between otherwise-ambiguous instants.

Comment: Do I need to use different delimiter for different culture?

Comment: @Twix What delimiter you are talking about exactly? Since your string has `:` as a `TimeSeparator`, the culture need to have it as well.

Comment: How this solution will work for different timezone. I mean `GMT` and `India Standard Time)` this may depend on the user's culture.

Comment: @Twix No, it won't I told you, `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` are timezone _awareness_. Take a look at NodaTime instead.

Comment: ok thanks...but I have to do this in c# only without using any other tool or package