# How to convert string value Jul 28 00:00 to datetime in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

Need to convert string value `Jul 28 00:00` to datetime value in the format `yyyy-MM-dd AM 00:00` ?

Which is the best way for doing it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: what have you found and tried so far on this? Further where are getting stuck in relation to this? You certainly cannot expect the SO community to do the ground work for you.

Comment: What year should code use? In your string value without year..

Comment: It seems like you did not try to solve the problem, number of examples can be found on this topic.

Comment: Welcome to [SO] please read the [FAQ]'s and [ask]. Always do a google search before asking and provide the code you've tried that doesn't work. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

how about this

```
string[] initDate = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
string[] time = initDate[2].Split(':');

DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.ParseExact(initDate[0], "MMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month, int.Parse(initDate[1]), int.Parse(time[0]), int.Parse(time[1]), 0);
string newDate = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd tt HH:mm");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
var dateTimeString = "Jul 28 00:00";
var required = dateTimeString.ToDateTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd tt hh:mm");
```

You need to add following class into your project i-e `DateTimeRoutines.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
/// <summary>
/// Miscellaneous and parsing methods for DateTime
/// </summary>
public static class DateTimeRoutines
{
    #region miscellaneous methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Amount of seconds elapsed between 1970-01-01 00:00:00 and the date-time.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="date_time">date-time</param>
    /// <returns>seconds</returns>
    public static uint GetSecondsSinceUnixEpoch(this DateTime date_time)
    {
        TimeSpan t = date_time - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
        int ss = (int)t.TotalSeconds;
        if (ss < 0)
            return 0;
        return (uint)ss;
    }

    #endregion

    #region parsing definitions

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines a substring where date-time was found and result of conversion
    /// </summary>
    public class ParsedDateTime
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Index of first char of a date substring found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public int IndexOfDate = -1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Length a date substring found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public int LengthOfDate = -1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Index of first char of a time substring found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public int IndexOfTime = -1;
        /// <summary>
        /// Length of a time substring found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public int LengthOfTime = -1;
        /// <summary>
        /// DateTime found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public DateTime DateTime;
        /// <summary>
        /// True if a date was found within the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public bool IsDateFound;
        /// <summary>
        /// True if a time was found within the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public bool IsTimeFound;
        /// <summary>
        /// UTC offset if it was found within the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public TimeSpan UtcOffset;
        /// <summary>
        /// True if UTC offset was found in the string
        /// </summary>
        readonly public bool IsUtcOffsetFound;
        /// <summary>
        /// Utc gotten from DateTime if IsUtcOffsetFound is True
        /// </summary>
        public DateTime UtcDateTime;

        public ParsedDateTime(int index_of_date, int length_of_date, int index_of_time, int length_of_time, DateTime date_time)
        {
            IndexOfDate = index_of_date;
            LengthOfDate = length_of_date;
            IndexOfTime = index_of_time;
            LengthOfTime = length_of_time;
            DateTime = date_time;
            IsDateFound = index_of_date > -1;
            IsTimeFound = index_of_time > -1;
            UtcOffset = new TimeSpan(25, 0, 0);
            IsUtcOffsetFound = false;
            UtcDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
        }

        public ParsedDateTime(int index_of_date, int length_of_date, int index_of_time, int length_of_time, DateTime date_time, TimeSpan utc_offset)
        {
            IndexOfDate = index_of_date;
            LengthOfDate = length_of_date;
            IndexOfTime = index_of_time;
            LengthOfTime = length_of_time;
            DateTime = date_time;
            IsDateFound = index_of_date > -1;
            IsTimeFound = index_of_time > -1;
            UtcOffset = utc_offset;
            IsUtcOffsetFound = Math.Abs(utc_offset.TotalHours) < 12;
            if (!IsUtcOffsetFound)
                UtcDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            else
            {
                if (index_of_date < 0)//to avoid negative date exception when date is undefined
                {
                    TimeSpan ts = date_time.TimeOfDay + utc_offset;
                    if (ts < new TimeSpan(0))
                        UtcDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 2) + ts;
                    else
                        UtcDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1) + ts;
                }
                else
                    UtcDateTime = date_time + utc_offset;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Date that is accepted in the following cases:
    /// - no date was parsed by TryParseDateOrTime();
    /// - no year was found by TryParseDate();
    /// It is ignored if DefaultDateIsNow = true was set after DefaultDate 
    /// </summary>
    public static DateTime DefaultDate
    {
        set
        {
            _DefaultDate = value;
            DefaultDateIsNow = false;
        }
        get
        {
            if (DefaultDateIsNow)
                return DateTime.Now;
            else
                return _DefaultDate;
        }
    }
    static DateTime _DefaultDate = DateTime.Now;

    /// <summary>
    /// If true then DefaultDate property is ignored and DefaultDate is always DateTime.Now
    /// </summary>
    public static bool DefaultDateIsNow = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines default date-time format.
    /// </summary>
    public enum DateTimeFormat
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// month number goes before day number
        /// </summary>
        USA_DATE,
        /// <summary>
        /// day number goes before month number
        /// </summary>
        UK_DATE,
        ///// <summary>
        ///// time is specifed through AM or PM
        ///// </summary>
        //USA_TIME,
    }

    #endregion

    #region parsing derived methods for DateTime output

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date and time within the passed string and return it as DateTime structure. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date and/or time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="date_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if both date and time were found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDateTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out DateTime date_time)
    {
        ParsedDateTime parsed_date_time;
        if (!TryParseDateTime(str, default_format, out parsed_date_time))
        {
            date_time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        date_time = parsed_date_time.DateTime;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date and/or time within the passed string and return it as DateTime structure. 
    /// If only date was found, time in the returned DateTime is always 0:0:0.
    /// If only time was found, date in the returned DateTime is DefaultDate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date and(or) time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="date_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if date and/or time was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDateOrTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out DateTime date_time)
    {
        ParsedDateTime parsed_date_time;
        if (!TryParseDateOrTime(str, default_format, out parsed_date_time))
        {
            date_time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        date_time = parsed_date_time.DateTime;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find time within the passed string and return it as DateTime structure. 
    /// It recognizes only time while ignoring date, so date in the returned DateTime is always 1/1/1.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="time">parsed time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if time was found, else false</returns>
    public static bool TryParseTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out DateTime time)
    {
        ParsedDateTime parsed_time;
        if (!TryParseTime(str, default_format, out parsed_time, null))
        {
            time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        time = parsed_time.DateTime;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date within the passed string and return it as DateTime structure. 
    /// It recognizes only date while ignoring time, so time in the returned DateTime is always 0:0:0.
    /// If year of the date was not found then it accepts the current year. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="date">parsed date output</param>
    /// <returns>true if date was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDate(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out DateTime date)
    {
        ParsedDateTime parsed_date;
        if (!TryParseDate(str, default_format, out parsed_date))
        {
            date = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        date = parsed_date.DateTime;
        return true;
    }

    #endregion

    #region parsing derived methods for ParsedDateTime output

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date and time within the passed string and return it as ParsedDateTime object. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date-time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_date_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if both date and time were found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDateTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_date_time)
    {
        if (DateTimeRoutines.TryParseDateOrTime(str, default_format, out parsed_date_time)
            && parsed_date_time.IsDateFound
            && parsed_date_time.IsTimeFound
            )
            return true;

        parsed_date_time = null;
        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find time within the passed string and return it as ParsedDateTime object. 
    /// It recognizes only time while ignoring date, so date in the returned ParsedDateTime is always 1/1/1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date-time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if time was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_time)
    {
        return TryParseTime(str, default_format, out parsed_time, null);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date and/or time within the passed string and return it as ParsedDateTime object. 
    /// If only date was found, time in the returned ParsedDateTime is always 0:0:0.
    /// If only time was found, date in the returned ParsedDateTime is DefaultDate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date-time</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_date_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <returns>true if date or time was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDateOrTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_date_time)
    {
        parsed_date_time = null;

        ParsedDateTime parsed_date;
        ParsedDateTime parsed_time;
        if (!TryParseDate(str, default_format, out parsed_date))
        {
            if (!TryParseTime(str, default_format, out parsed_time, null))
                return false;

            DateTime date_time = new DateTime(DefaultDate.Year, DefaultDate.Month, DefaultDate.Day, parsed_time.DateTime.Hour, parsed_time.DateTime.Minute, parsed_time.DateTime.Second);
            parsed_date_time = new ParsedDateTime(-1, -1, parsed_time.IndexOfTime, parsed_time.LengthOfTime, date_time, parsed_time.UtcOffset);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!TryParseTime(str, default_format, out parsed_time, parsed_date))
            {
                DateTime date_time = new DateTime(parsed_date.DateTime.Year, parsed_date.DateTime.Month, parsed_date.DateTime.Day, 0, 0, 0);
                parsed_date_time = new ParsedDateTime(parsed_date.IndexOfDate, parsed_date.LengthOfDate, -1, -1, date_time);
            }
            else
            {
                DateTime date_time = new DateTime(parsed_date.DateTime.Year, parsed_date.DateTime.Month, parsed_date.DateTime.Day, parsed_time.DateTime.Hour, parsed_time.DateTime.Minute, parsed_time.DateTime.Second);
                parsed_date_time = new ParsedDateTime(parsed_date.IndexOfDate, parsed_date.LengthOfDate, parsed_time.IndexOfTime, parsed_time.LengthOfTime, date_time, parsed_time.UtcOffset);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(this string dateValue, DateTimeFormat dateFormat = DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE)
    {
        DateTime date;
        dateValue.TryParseDateOrTime(dateFormat, out date);
        return date;
    }

    #endregion

    #region parsing base methods

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find time within the passed string (relatively to the passed parsed_date if any) and return it as ParsedDateTime object.
    /// It recognizes only time while ignoring date, so date in the returned ParsedDateTime is always 1/1/1
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_time">parsed date-time output</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_date">ParsedDateTime object if the date was found within this string, else NULL</param>
    /// <returns>true if time was found, else false</returns>
    public static bool TryParseTime(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_time, ParsedDateTime parsed_date)
    {
        parsed_time = null;

        string time_zone_r;
        if (default_format == DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE)
            time_zone_r = @"(?:\s*(?'time_zone'UTC|GMT|CST|EST))?";
        else
            time_zone_r = @"(?:\s*(?'time_zone'UTC|GMT))?";

        Match m;
        if (parsed_date != null && parsed_date.IndexOfDate > -1)
        {//look around the found date
            //look for <date> hh:mm:ss <UTC offset> 
            m = Regex.Match(str.Substring(parsed_date.IndexOfDate + parsed_date.LengthOfDate), @"(?<=^\s*,?\s+|^\s*at\s*|^\s*[T\-]\s*)(?'hour'\d{2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*:\s*(?'second'\d{2})\s+(?'offset_sign'[\+\-])(?'offset_hh'\d{2}):?(?'offset_mm'\d{2})(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (!m.Success)
                //look for <date> [h]h:mm[:ss] [PM/AM] [UTC/GMT] 
                m = Regex.Match(str.Substring(parsed_date.IndexOfDate + parsed_date.LengthOfDate), @"(?<=^\s*,?\s+|^\s*at\s*|^\s*[T\-]\s*)(?'hour'\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*(?::\s*(?'second'\d{2}))?(?:\s*(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm))?" + time_zone_r + @"(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (!m.Success)
                //look for [h]h:mm:ss [PM/AM] [UTC/GMT] <date>
                m = Regex.Match(str.Substring(0, parsed_date.IndexOfDate), @"(?<=^|[^\d])(?'hour'\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*(?::\s*(?'second'\d{2}))?(?:\s*(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm))?" + time_zone_r + @"(?=$|[\s,]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (!m.Success)
                //look for [h]h:mm:ss [PM/AM] [UTC/GMT] within <date>
                m = Regex.Match(str.Substring(parsed_date.IndexOfDate, parsed_date.LengthOfDate), @"(?<=^|[^\d])(?'hour'\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*(?::\s*(?'second'\d{2}))?(?:\s*(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm))?" + time_zone_r + @"(?=$|[\s,]+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }
        else//look anywhere within string
        {
            //look for hh:mm:ss <UTC offset> 
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=^|\s+|\s*T\s*)(?'hour'\d{2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*:\s*(?'second'\d{2})\s+(?'offset_sign'[\+\-])(?'offset_hh'\d{2}):?(?'offset_mm'\d{2})?(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            if (!m.Success)
                //look for [h]h:mm[:ss] [PM/AM] [UTC/GMT]
                m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=^|\s+|\s*T\s*)(?'hour'\d{1,2})\s*:\s*(?'minute'\d{2})\s*(?::\s*(?'second'\d{2}))?(?:\s*(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm))?" + time_zone_r + @"(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled);
        }

        if (!m.Success)
            return false;

        //try
        //{
        int hour = int.Parse(m.Groups["hour"].Value);
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 23)
            return false;

        int minute = int.Parse(m.Groups["minute"].Value);
        if (minute < 0 || minute > 59)
            return false;

        int second = 0;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["second"].Value))
        {
            second = int.Parse(m.Groups["second"].Value);
            if (second < 0 || second > 59)
                return false;
        }

        if (string.Compare(m.Groups["ampm"].Value, "PM", true) == 0 && hour < 12)
            hour += 12;
        else if (string.Compare(m.Groups["ampm"].Value, "AM", true) == 0 && hour == 12)
            hour -= 12;

        DateTime date_time = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, hour, minute, second);

        if (m.Groups["offset_hh"].Success)
        {
            int offset_hh = int.Parse(m.Groups["offset_hh"].Value);
            int offset_mm = 0;
            if (m.Groups["offset_mm"].Success)
                offset_mm = int.Parse(m.Groups["offset_mm"].Value);
            TimeSpan utc_offset = new TimeSpan(offset_hh, offset_mm, 0);
            if (m.Groups["offset_sign"].Value == "-")
                utc_offset = -utc_offset;
            parsed_time = new ParsedDateTime(-1, -1, m.Index, m.Length, date_time, utc_offset);
            return true;
        }

        if (m.Groups["time_zone"].Success)
        {
            TimeSpan utc_offset;
            switch (m.Groups["time_zone"].Value)
            {
                case "UTC":
                case "GMT":
                    utc_offset = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case "CST":
                    utc_offset = new TimeSpan(-6, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case "EST":
                    utc_offset = new TimeSpan(-5, 0, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception("Time zone: " + m.Groups["time_zone"].Value + " is not defined.");
            }
            parsed_time = new ParsedDateTime(-1, -1, m.Index, m.Length, date_time, utc_offset);
            return true;
        }

        parsed_time = new ParsedDateTime(-1, -1, m.Index, m.Length, date_time);
        //}
        //catch(Exception e)
        //{
        //    return false;
        //}
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Tries to find date within the passed string and return it as ParsedDateTime object. 
    /// It recognizes only date while ignoring time, so time in the returned ParsedDateTime is always 0:0:0.
    /// If year of the date was not found then it accepts the current year. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">string that contains date</param>
    /// <param name="default_format">format to be used preferably in ambivalent instances</param>
    /// <param name="parsed_date">parsed date output</param>
    /// <returns>true if date was found, else false</returns>
    static public bool TryParseDate(this string str, DateTimeFormat default_format, out ParsedDateTime parsed_date)
    {
        parsed_date = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
            return false;

        //look for dd/mm/yy
        Match m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=^|[^\d])(?'day'\d{1,2})\s*(?'separator'[\\/\.])+\s*(?'month'\d{1,2})\s*\'separator'+\s*(?'year'\d{2}|\d{4})(?=$|[^\d])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            DateTime date;
            if ((default_format ^ DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE) == DateTimeFormat.USA_DATE)
            {
                if (!convert_to_date(int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value), out date))
                    return false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (!convert_to_date(int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value), out date))
                    return false;
            }
            parsed_date = new ParsedDateTime(m.Index, m.Length, -1, -1, date);
            return true;
        }

        //look for [yy]yy-mm-dd
        m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=^|[^\d])(?'year'\d{2}|\d{4})\s*(?'separator'[\-])\s*(?'month'\d{1,2})\s*\'separator'+\s*(?'day'\d{1,2})(?=$|[^\d])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            DateTime date;
            if (!convert_to_date(int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value), int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value), out date))
                return false;
            parsed_date = new ParsedDateTime(m.Index, m.Length, -1, -1, date);
            return true;
        }

        //look for month dd yyyy
        m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w])(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*\s+(?'day'\d{1,2})(?:-?st|-?th|-?rd|-?nd)?\s*,?\s*(?'year'\d{4})(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!m.Success)
            //look for dd month [yy]yy
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w:])(?'day'\d{1,2})(?:-?st\s+|-?th\s+|-?rd\s+|-?nd\s+|-|\s+)(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*(?:\s*,?\s*|-)'?(?'year'\d{2}|\d{4})(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!m.Success)
            //look for yyyy month dd
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w])(?'year'\d{4})\s+(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*\s+(?'day'\d{1,2})(?:-?st|-?th|-?rd|-?nd)?(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!m.Success)
            //look for month dd hh:mm:ss MDT|UTC yyyy
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w])(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*\s+(?'day'\d{1,2})\s+\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}\s+(?:MDT|UTC)\s+(?'year'\d{4})(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (!m.Success)
            //look for  month dd [yyyy]
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?:^|[^\d\w])(?'month'Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[uarychilestmbro]*\s+(?'day'\d{1,2})(?:-?st|-?th|-?rd|-?nd)?(?:\s*,?\s*(?'year'\d{4}))?(?=$|[^\d\w])", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (m.Success)
        {
            int month = -1;
            int index_of_date = m.Index;
            int length_of_date = m.Length;

            switch (m.Groups["month"].Value)
            {
                case "Jan":
                case "JAN":
                    month = 1;
                    break;
                case "Feb":
                case "FEB":
                    month = 2;
                    break;
                case "Mar":
                case "MAR":
                    month = 3;
                    break;
                case "Apr":
                case "APR":
                    month = 4;
                    break;
                case "May":
                case "MAY":
                    month = 5;
                    break;
                case "Jun":
                case "JUN":
                    month = 6;
                    break;
                case "Jul":
                    month = 7;
                    break;
                case "Aug":
                case "AUG":
                    month = 8;
                    break;
                case "Sep":
                case "SEP":
                    month = 9;
                    break;
                case "Oct":
                case "OCT":
                    month = 10;
                    break;
                case "Nov":
                case "NOV":
                    month = 11;
                    break;
                case "Dec":
                case "DEC":
                    month = 12;
                    break;
            }

            int year;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups["year"].Value))
                year = int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value);
            else
                year = DefaultDate.Year;

            DateTime date;
            if (!convert_to_date(year, month, int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value), out date))
                return false;
            parsed_date = new ParsedDateTime(index_of_date, length_of_date, -1, -1, date);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    static bool convert_to_date(int year, int month, int day, out DateTime date)
    {
        if (year >= 100)
        {
            if (year < 1000)
            {
                date = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
            if (year > 30)
                year += 1900;
            else
                year += 2000;

        try
        {
            date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
        }
        catch
        {
            date = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are giving an answer to a particular question, not publishing your  whole DateTime parsing library?

Answer (score 1):

You should do it with 2 steps;

- First, parse it your string with en *english-based* culture (like [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) with `MMM dd HH:mm` format.
- Second, generate it's string representation with `yyyy-MM-dd tt HH:mm` format using a culture that has [`AMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.amdesignator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`PMDesignator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.pmdesignator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties are not empty space.

---

```
string s = "Jul 28 00:00";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "MMM dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd tt 00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Dump();
}
```

This will generate `2015-07-28 AM 00:00` string.

<kbd>[`Here a demo.`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6vzSmW)</kbd>