# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following code in my project (which was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12257557).

```
string r = "08/05/2015";
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(r, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
```

the value inside `r` is in `MM/dd/yyyy`

For the ParseExact I am getting the error

> string was not recognized as a valid date time.

I gone through most of the question in stackoverflow all are giving the above codes. Do I am missing anything?

Comment: Follow this, it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31823320/how-to-convert-string-value-jul-28-0000-to-datetime-in-c-sharp/31823421#31823421

Comment: Funny how a date that's in `MM/dd/yyyy` is deemed invalid when asking it to be parsed as `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: What part of `DateTime.ParseExact` don't you understand?

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(r, "MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(r, "yyyy-MM-dd", culture);
```

with

```
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(r, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse exact required exact format. So format must be  MM/dd/yyyy.

```
string r = "08/05/2015";
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US", true);
DateTime t1 = DateTime.ParseExact(r, "MM/dd/yyyy", culture);
```

for details [check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)