# Sort DataTable String

Tags: c#, sorting

So I am working on a site that an intern did, we have a date column in out DataTable but it is just a string, so when doing `dt.DefaultView.Sort = "DATE ASC"` it is sorting weird, here is an example.

```
Date:
01/31/2015
02/10/2015
02/15/2015
02/15/2014
02/20/2015
02/20/2014
02/21/2014
```

As you can see by this, it is sorting by the first two mm/dd but year is mixed into this, so we have 2014 dates with 2015 etc.  I need to sort first by the year and then by the other two.  Any ideas how to do this since the date is just a string?

Comment: What data type has `DATE` field?

Comment: Convert the strings to actual `DateTime`s similar to this question, then sort? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a new column to the `DataTable` that has a `DateTime` type and sort it by that. That way you get "real" date sorting. If you can edit the SQL procedure that is loading the data into the `DataTable` to return the date, that would be best, but otherwise you can do that in code:

```
var dt = GetMyDataTable(); //however you're loading the table
dt.Columns.Add("MyDate", typeof (DateTime));
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
     row["MyDate"] = DateTime.Parse(row["MyStringDate"].ToString());
}
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "MyDate ASC";
```

Note that if you have a lot of rows, this is probably not the way to go, and the better approach is modifying the procedure to return the date as a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering the column as string.  Put the column as date or use the format `YYYY-MM-DD` to order the column.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it would work but try to add `cast` because your `DATE` field is `varchar` type and sorted as string :

```
dt.DefaultView.Sort = "CAST(DATE as Date) ASC"
```

Comment: If you aren't sure if it will work, it should be a comment, not answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want/can use Linq then this should work:

```
var sortedDataTable = 
  (from row in yourDataTable.AsEnumerable()
   let correctDate= Convert.ToDateTime(row.Field<string>("DATE"))     
   orderby correctDate
   select row).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a Column Expression?

```
table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("YMD") {
  Expression = "SUBSTRING(Date,7,4)+SUBSTRING(Date,1,2)+SUBSTRING(Date,4,2)"
});
var view = table.DefaultView;
view.Sort = "YMD";
```