# Convert string Time format to Time format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a string

> 10:30AM

I want to convert into

> 10:30:00 AM

The resulting string should be in time format(HH:MM:SS AM/PM). How do I  do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You should probably parse to a `DateTime` (ignoring the date) in the current format, then reformat to the format you want.

Comment: You want to convert `"10:30AM"` to `"10:30:00 AM"`??

Comment: [Parsing Date and Time Strings in the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h3syy57(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is one of them times where I wished *"this is just plain laziness"* was a close reason

Comment: yes i  want to convert "10:30AM" to "10:30:00 AM"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `ParseExact` method to convert a custom string to a `DateTime`, then use `ToString` method to convert it to your desired string format.

```
 var result = DateTime.ParseExact("10:30AM", "hh:mmtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      .ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
//result : "10:30:00 AM"
```

In the `DateTime` formatting you may remember these notes:

- **hh:** hour part
- **mm:** minute part
- **ss:** second part
- **tt:** represent AM/PM part

Comment: It Works... thank you very much...

Comment: One pitfall here, you aren't using `.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`. So this works only if the current culture uses the `AM/PM` designator. Otherwise you get: `"10:30:00 "`

Comment: @TimSchmelter good point.

Answer (score 2):

You want to convert `"10:30AM"` to `"10:30:00 AM"`? Use `DateTime` methods:

```
string time = "10:30AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "hh:mmtt", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
string result = dt.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

worth reading: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Does `DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo` has any benefit over `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad: Not that I know of. I'm using it because i'm not interested in all culture settings but only those related to datetime. If i parse numbers i use `NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo`. I guess it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Good at least this is a different approach.