# How to convert string date to following date format dd/MM/yyyy t:m:s in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to convert date format from string to `dd/MM/yyyy tt:mm:ss` in C# for example convert

```
string = "2015-07-21T23:00:00.000Z"
```

to

```
{21/07/2015 00:00:00}
```

Comment: your input is a date or a string?

Comment: Have you tried DateTime.Parse method

Comment: Your title says `t:m:s` and your question says `tt:mm:ss`? Are you _really_ sure you know what `tt` means exactly? You mean `HH:mm:ss` instead? And your string and DateTime value does not match.

Comment: I have tried DateTime.Parse but i did mistake somewhere ... not working!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime

Comment: `DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would parse it to `DateTime` with [`DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) enumeration since it is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format then use it's [`Date` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date9.aspx) to set it's time part to midnight.

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse("2015-07-21T23:00:00.000Z", null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Date.ToString("dd'/'MM'/'yyyy HH:mm:ss")); // 21/07/2015 00:00:00
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qark7I)</kbd>.