# Returning a date from a class

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

What I want to do is have a user enter a date and have a class that returns the last day of the month.  So, I've put this in my class module:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(DateTime MyDate)
    {
        DateTime today = MyDate;
        DateTime EOM = new DateTime(today.Year,today.Month,
                           DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year,
                           today.Month));
            return EOM;
    }
}
```

In my code-behind, I have this:

```
DateTime LDOM = StringExtensions.LastDayOfMonth(txtCIT.Text);
```

I've also tried hard-coding a date like:

```
DateTime LDOM = StringExtensions.LastDayOfMonth('1/12/2016');
```

I'm getting these errors:

> Error 14  The best overloaded method match for
>   'ClientDPL.StringExtensions.LastDayOfMonth(System.DateTime)' has some
>   invalid arguments

and

> Error 15  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you're going to put it in a class called StringExtensions, there's an expectation that it's an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) and that it accepts a string as the first parameter. Your method doesn't do either of these.

Comment: Are you sure you're using single quotes in the second example?  If you were you'd get an error about too many characters in character literal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mason pointed out in comment, a probably better way to do it would be to use a DateTime extension method similar to:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime date)
    {
        DateTime EOM = new DateTime(
            date.Year,date.Month,
            DateTime.DaysInMonth(
                date.Year,
                date.Month
            )
        );

        return EOM;
    }
}
```

Can be used like:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.LastDayOfMonth());
```

See it in action at:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/59Oj7c

Comment: All the answers here were great and useful, but I ended up using this one so I'll give the checkmark here.  I may explore Vadim's TryParse idea at a later date.

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to pass `String` argument to the method that need a `DateTime` argument. Then you need [parse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx) your value first:

```
var textCitValue = DateTime.Parse(txtCIT.Text);
DateTime LDOM = StringExtensions.LastDayOfMonth(textCitValue);
```

The better way is to use safe method [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) that will never throws an exception

```
DateTime textCitDateTime;
if(DateTime.TryParse(txtCIT.Text, out textCitDateTime))
{
    DateTime LDOM = StringExtensions.LastDayOfMonth(textCitValue);
    // your logic here
}
else
{
    // handle invalid textbox date here
}
```

Also, you have unclear naming. Your `StringExtensions` class has a method that is not an extension method and uses `DateTime` as a parameter. It'll be better to rename your class and change `LastDayOfMonth` signature like next:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime date) { ... }
}
```

Then you can call this method to as a `DateTime` public instance method:

```
DateTime LDOM = textCitValue.LastDayOfMonth();
```

You can also change method signature to `public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(string date)` but it will break [single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for your method.

Comment: Alternatively, `LastDayOfMonth()` can be changed to accept a `string` argument and then the logic you show here can be encapsulated in that method.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes it can, but then `LastDayOfMonth()` will handle only one format of input string (or we will need to add extra parameter with formatting). Now it encapsulates exactly one task and has a single responsibility.

Comment: I'm unclear how `LastDayOfMonth()` will handle only one format. You make a good point about single responsibility. My suggestion probably breaks this.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice What Vadim means is that if it takes a string and then parses it to a `DateTime` the method would need to know the format vs. letting the format be determined by the caller before passing a parsed `DateTime`.

Comment: @juharr well in one isolated case it's no sense. But in the different parts of application we may need to call `LastDayOfMonth()` with different date formats or for DateTime object. Nowthequestion is: "What actually should LastDayOfMount does?". Method name and SOLID principles tells that DateTime is better candidate to input parameter.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is expecting a parameter of `DateTime`.

In your calls:

```
DateTime LDOM = StringExtensions.LastDayOfMonth(txtCIT.Text);
```

and

```
DateTime LDOM = StringExtensions.LastDayOfMonth('1/12/2016');
```

in both cases you're not passing a `DateTime`. You need to convert your `string` to a `DateTime` prior to calling the function.

Lots of methods of doing that here: [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: Alternatively, the `LastDayOfMonth()` method could be changed to accept a `string` parameter and handle the parsing internally.

Comment: Actually the second isn't a string, it's an invalid char literal.

Comment: @Kritner I'm guessing that was a typo by the OP or they would have gotten a completely different error message.

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm not just re-stating the question by presenting this answer and apologize in advance, but I would be more privy to just declaring extensions for both types along the lines of the following (note the `Nullable` return type denoted by the question mark):

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonth(this DateTime self)
    {
        return new DateTime(self.Year, self.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(self.Year, self.Month));
    }

    public static DateTime? LastDayOfMonth(this string self)
    {
        DateTime dt;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(self, out dt))
            return null;

        return dt.LastDayOfMonth();
    }
}
```

Then to use it in code:

```
private void App()
{
    var lastDayFromDate = (DateTime.Now).LastDayOfMonth();
    var lastDayFromString = "1/12/2016".LastDayOfMonth();

    if (lastDayFromString != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: For the first method, the one with `DateTime`, there is no need to return a Nullable `DateTime`: if will never return null. I would declare it with a regular `DateTime` return value, so client code will not need to check "if it's not null"

Comment: @GianPaolo Right you are :)