# Most efficient way to convert this string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I receive DateTime in this format => yyyyMMddHHmmss e.g. 20160214204032

Due to its somewhat unique format, I can't just use Convert.ToDateTime -- I tried, it didn't work.

It's easy enough to create a helper method that would parse the components of this date e.g

`var year = myString.Substring(0,4);`

but I'm concerned that this may have poor performance.

Can anyone think of a better way to convert a string in this format to DateTime?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime

Comment: You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` with format parameter as `yyyyMMddHHmmss`. And use `DateTime.Year` to retrieve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot set format in `Convert.ToDateTime`. So, use `ParseExact` instead.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("20160214204032", "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Due to its somewhat unique format, I can't just use Convert.ToDateTime -- I tried, it didn't work.

It fails because `Convert.ToDateTime` tries to convert from your system Date Time Format and throws exception if it can't.

using String Functions is also bad to convert to DateTime so you can do

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("20160214204032", 
                                  "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
                                  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: This should be a comment