# Convert date string to a SQL readable date format

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert the date string  `Oct 21 2014 1:00 AM`  to `2014-10-21 01:00:00` or something that SQL Server can understand.

Comment: Is `Oct 21 2014 1:00 AM` a string or a datetime?

Comment: How do you work with database?

Comment: @TimFreese It is a string

Comment: Please see answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var dateString = "Oct 21 2014 1:00 AM";
DateTime result;
DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out result);
var sqlDate = result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that if you're using ADO.NET to communicate with your SQL Server, you shouldn't use a formatted date string as a query parameter. You should instead use a [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx) object. You can get it from your string by using either the [`DateTime.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx) methods:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("Oct 21 2014 1:00 AM"); // Use this as your query parameter.
```

However if you do decide to go with using a formatted string, the simplest way would be first parse it to as shown above, then you can use [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx) with a format string overload, to format your date as you want.

To get your example format:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("Oct 21 2014 1:00 AM");
string formatted = DateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); // 2014-10-21 01:00:00
```

Comment: Given the string provided and assuming it won't change, this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Please see answer here.

[Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

DateTime.ParseExact may work for you to convert in DateTime and then you can use `ToString(<format>)` with format to convert it in required string.

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` is only useful when you know the exact format beforehand, if you do not - it will fail. Also, assuming the string provided is the way the data will always be received, even `TryParse()` is redundant and he should use `Parse()` insead. `ParseExact` is only useful when the format is uncommon or of a different culture variation and won't parse with any other method. _Always_ use `.Parse()` or `.TryParse()` before resorting to `.ParseExact()`.