# how to input DateTime into MySQL via C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I'm having a huge issue with inputting DateTime into my MySQL db. MySQL reads datetime as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss while C# sees datetime as dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss. I have tried two different examples and both doesn't work.

**MODEL**

```
public class DateAndTime
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
//I Have two examples that doesn't work.
 var myDateTime = "2016-04-08 12:00:00" //this gives the error "cannot covert source 'string' to tartget type System.DateTime

 var myDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("2016-04-08 12:00:00") //this gives the error "Input string was not in a correct format."

var model =  new DateAndTime
{
   DateTime = myDateTime
};
```

So I'm stuck. I'ms sure someone out there has had this issue.

Comment: How are you creating your SQL statement?  If you use parameters then you shouldn't need to worry about formatting.

Comment: @juharr - the column DateTime in the table DateAndTime is in a MySQL db as yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss. I use nHibernate to write to the db but im not getting that far yet with this error.

Comment: You mean it's in the DB as a `varchar` instead of a `DateTime`?  Because `DateTime` does not have a specific format, it's actually just a numeric value.  The format used with SQL statements is just to make it so a human can understand it.

Comment: just double checked, db is datetime, class is DateTime, and var is DateTime.

Comment: In that case there should be a way to do this and not worry about the formatting, but you really need to show the code that actually creates the query or the specific ORM you are using as it's not a matter of how to format the `DateTime` as a string, but how to make your ORM correctly work with your DB when dealing with `DateTime`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Check:

[Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc165448.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: using this: var myDateTime = "2016-04-08 14:18:17"
and DateTime.ParseExact(myDateTime, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
i get error "Input string was not in a correct format." Perhaps it's incorrect because its missing AM/PM?

Comment: this is good. turns out i was converting it in the wrong format. THANKS I

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
myDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

myDateTime variable must be type DateTime.

or you can use this MySql function : STR_TO_DATE

```
STR_TO_DATE('4/8/2016 2:18:17 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')
```

[Specifier Format here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: using this still gives me the error "annot covert source 'string' to tartget type System.DateTime"

Comment: myDateTime variable must be type DateTime try : Convert.ToDateTime(myDateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Comment: yeah. i get this error when DateTime myDateTime = {4/8/2016 2:18:17 PM}.

Comment: try this function in your sql query : STR_TO_DATE('4/8/2016 2:18:17 PM', '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i:%s %p')

Answer (score 0):

I have this issue because of the datetime format in my machine. If your desktop is configured like dd/mm/yy(the / symbol instead of -) then you have to replace - with / before converting. Please let me know

Comment: My machine shows dd/mm/yyyy but it wouldnt matter because the end result has to write yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss so im able to convert it.