# Convert string to Datetime format dd-MMM-yyyy issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the account expiry date of the employee from database in a string variable and the values which is in this string variable is in the format  :  6/26/2016 9:14:03 AM. Now i want this format to be converted in dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm.How can i resolve this.

I tried the following code :

```
 DateTime passexpiredate = DateTime.ParseExact(app_user.GetPasswordExpiry(empCode), "dd-MMM-yyy hh:mm tt", null);
  lblPassExpiry.InnerText = "Password Expiry Date: "+passexpiredate.ToString();
```

Comment: First of all: a year by only three `yyy`? Seconds won't be parsed but are available... Month expected as text but given as numbers. Month 26? Also check the separator. Try [rtm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: this can provide you helpful guide http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime

Comment: I didn't found the solution there.kindly suggest me your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to pass the required date time format in `ToString()` method as mentioned below:

```
DateTime passexpiredate = DateTime.Parse(app_user.GetPasswordExpiry(empCode));
lblPassExpiry.InnerText = "Password Expiry Date: " + passexpiredate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyy hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: support for you :)

Comment: @AlinaAnjum Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Life is to easy using [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DateTime.ParseExact("12/02/21 10:56:09 AM", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt");
```

Comment: thanks but i got the solution.Support for your answer :)

Comment: no problem it will helpful for future users although it is concise answer. cheers!

Comment: i supported your answer dear

Answer (score 1):

You need to make DateTime from string  6/26/2016 9:14:03 AM. And then format it to dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss am/pm

Comment: var passexpiredate = DateTime.Parse("06/26/2016 9:14:03 AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);   lblPassExpiry.InnerText = "Password Expiry Date: " + passexpiredate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyy hh:mm tt");

Comment: thanks but i got the solution.Support for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.ParseExact` requires you to specify format exactly as it matches with string representation of datetime value. So that's not going to work for your case.

You will have to first convert string to `DateTime` instance and then format it while displaying.

```
string date = "6/26/2016 9:14:03 AM";
var dt = DateTime.Parse(date);
var dtStr = dt.ToString("dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt");
Console.WriteLine(dtStr); // Output: 26-14-2016 09:14:03 AM
```

Comment: thanks but i got the solution.Support for your answer :)