# How do I convert a date string from 'M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt' to 'yyyy-dd-mmTHH:mm:ss'? C#

Tags: c#, date, parsing, datetime, time

I have a string that looks like `5/27/2015 4:49:54 AM`

I need it to be in this format: `2015-27-05T04:49:54+08:00`

I tried converting it like so but it throws an error:

```
var convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(originalDate, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK",
                            new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
```

I also tried converting it like this but it doesn't seem to do anything, convertedDate ends up being the same as originalDate:

```
var convertedDate = String.Format("{0:u}", originalDate);
```

Comment: You have a string `"5/27/2015 4:49:54 AM"` and use `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK"` as format string in `ParseExact`? Of course that doesn't work.

Comment: You need to supply the format that you want to parse *from*, not to. That gives you a DateTime. However, you appear to need to add an offset, so the [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type might be more useful. Or maybe [Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) would be easier to use.

Comment: @TimSchmelter saying "Of course that doesn't work" isn't in any way helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string to Datetime format dd-MMM-yyyy issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179087/convert-string-to-datetime-format-dd-mmm-yyyy-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse first, then use your desired format string with `ToString` translate.

Try this:

```
string input = "5/27/2015 4:49:54 AM";
DateTime originalDate = DateTime.Parse(input);
string output = originalDate.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK");
```

You can swap out `DateTime.Parse` with `DateTime.ParseExact` if needed. `DateTime.Parse` will attempt to parse using your system culture. You can be more specific if you need/want to be.

Also, keep in mind that the `f` in the format string creates a mandatory decimal. To match your prescribed output, you should use `F` or omit.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

First parse the original `string` to a `DateTime`. Then format the `DateTime` to a `string` of the desired format.

```
var originalDate = "5/27/2015 4:49:54 AM";
var result = DateTime.ParseExact(originalDate, "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    .ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzzz");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outputs

> 2015-05-27T04:49:54-04:00

Note that that the timezone offset you get will be dependent on the culture of the machine this runs on because it is not specified in the original string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
string inputString = "05/27/2015 04:49:54 AM";

DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(inputString, "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt",
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string outputString = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz");
```

Output string will return the value as "2015-05-27T04:49:54+08:00".

Answer (score 0):

Try `convertedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:sszzz")`, date and time settings on your local machine may affect how the output is formatted so you can't always rely on the in-built formatting strings.

Answer (score 0):

To parse `"5/27/2015 4:49:54 AM"` you should use this format string: `"M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt"`

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "5/27/2015 4:49:54 AM",
    "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt",
    new CultureInfo("en-US", true));
```

Then you can use `DateTime.ToString` with the desired format-string which seems to be `"yyyy-dd-MM'T'hh:mm:sszzz"` to get `2015-27-05T04:49:54+08:00` as output:

```
string result = convertedDate.ToString("yyyy-dd-MM'T'hh:mm:sszzz");  // zzz to get UTC offset
```

See: [The "zzz" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.100).aspx#zzzSpecifier)