# Converting string dd/mm to datetime

Tags: c#

[Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

As the above link says I can do conversion if I'm having a the complete dd/mm/yyyy,But I'm having only dd/mm **not the year field**.

I have achieve it by changing the date to mm/dd format and using Convert.ToDateTime(date).So any help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse that string. Just remember that the Month part is MM not mm (minutes)

```
string data = "01/01";
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParseExact(data, "dd/MM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToLongDateString());
```

Of course the missing year is assumed to be the current year

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn more about specifiers for parsing custom date's.

Put your string variable instead of CustomDate field.

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact(CustomDate, "dd/MM",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the function `DateTime.TryParseExact` since you can use it within an If - else structure very easily

```
private DateTime date;
private myString = "23/04";

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(myString, "dd/MM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    myDate = date;
}
else
{
    //do nothing
}
```

With this you can catch errors when parsing the string.