# How to parse "20161114T000000Z" to DateTime object in sitecore

Tags: c#, sitecore

The datetime type in sitecore field I retrieved through query is "20161114T000000Z" string.

**Question:**

1. What is T and Z?
2. How should parse it to DateTime object?

I read some related questions and found DateTime.TryParseExact() in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime?rq=1) could solve the problem, but still I don't know what is T and Z mean.

Please provide some sample code.

Comment: T is the separator between Date and Time. Z is for zulu time or UTC.

Comment: "Please provide some sample code". I think you might be confused on what the purpose of Stack Overflow is. We're not here to write code for you. Please read [ask]. For the T and Z, read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: @JoshJ Any suggestion about the format string for parsing it? e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff"

Comment: Not beating up anyone. Just informing you of the rules of the site. In fact, if anyone should be offended, it should be me, since it appears you feel your time is more valuable than mine.

Comment: Welcome Nicolas.  Mike's right, but I answered anyway, since I was bored. But be a good community member and please read this: [Ask]  On most days your question would have been closed before I could answer.

Comment: I'm going to side with Mike on this one. I gave you the answer to your first part of the question and it should be enough for you to figure out the second part. Show us code that you are trying and we can help more. No one benefits from a copy and paste code service, but if you learn some new tricks you may be able to teach them to someone else later on. Good luck!

Comment: Answered here: http://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4833/what-is-the-datetime-format-used-by-sitecores-date-datetime-field-types-and-h

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The T is just a delimiter.  The Z tells us the time is in UTC. What we're looking at is a variant of [ISO-8601 Combined Date and Time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

To parse this string you could use

```
using System.Globalization;

var s = "20161114T000000Z";
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Microsoft' latest [guidance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384267(v=vs.110).aspx) is to prefer the [DateTimeOffset structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) for unambiguously storing a point in time, so perhaps you should use this instead:

```
var s = "20161114T000000Z";
var d = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Best practice is actually to use the built in Sitecore methods e.g. Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime([CanBeNull] string isoDate, DateTime defaultValue, bool treatLegacyDatesAsUtc)

Comment: @geedubb Do you have a citation for that? I am curious why it is better. Will it work with the OP's example (which is not quite exactly a standard ISO date/time string)?

Comment: var isoDate = "20161114T000000Z";
Response.Write( Sitecore.DateUtil.IsoDateToDateTime(isoDate, DateTime.Now, true) ); -> will print 14/11/2016 00:00:00. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/utc/datetime/datetime_best_practices