# How to convert "24-04-2015 00:00:00" String to datetime in c#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have string `"24-04-2015 00:00:00"`. I need convert it into datetime and store it in database.

If i pass `"24-04-2015 00:00:00"` as a string to database, I am getting the error

> "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a DateTime."

And also if i use `DateTime.ParseExact("24-04-2015 00:00:00", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
 I am getting below error

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: Clearly `24-04-2015` and `yyyy-MM-dd` don't match. Did you do any research on this subject?

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" won't match your input string. Swap yyyy and dd, and it should work. Also, beware of Time Zone : is your time is local hour or UTC hour ? You can specify this with the last parameter (enum DateTimeStyles or something like this) of ParseExact method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
//Add namespace 
using System.Globalization;

// Code to convert the string to datetime
string datetime="24-04-2015 00:00:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(datetime, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Above code is tested.