# Get custom string from SQL and turn into c# date object to sort by

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a table that has a sql column with a date as a string like 'January 1, 2018'. I'm trying to turn that into a DateTime object in C# so I can use it to sort a list by. I'm currently grouping everything by the ID so I can return the highest revision. This is working great but I also need to OrderByDescending date from a the column that represents a date. The below code will order everything alphanumerically but I need to sort by DateTime.

```
    using (dbEntities entities = new dbEntities())
    {
        var db = entities.db_table
        .GroupBy(x => x.ID) //grouping by the id
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => 
                     y.REVISIONID).FirstOrDefault());
       return db.OrderBy(e => e.Date_String).ToList(); 
    }
```

Thanks, I appreciate any help on this!

Comment: see this SO for how to parse your string to datetime in C#:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime -- if you need the datetimes for anything other than sorting you can probably add a field to your model and maintain both your db string and your datetime, in this case do your conversion and sort in 2 separate steps.  If you don't need it outside of the sort, utilize one of the linq statements from the answers.

Comment: Why don't you convert the string to a date within the database instead on the client?

Comment: for future proofing, you should probably try to convert that field if at all possible and just maintain a datetime object in the database.  It will save you many headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to materialize the objects and use LINQ-to-Objects to do the conversion to a C# DateTime.

```
return db.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Date_String)).ToList();
```

If at all possible, I would strongly recommend changing your column to a `datetime2` or `datetimeoffset` at the database level, though.

Comment: Exactly what needed! I'll look into changing the column at db level.

Comment: @dmod40: Excellent. If you *don't* end up changing the data type, do be aware that `DateTime.Parse` will behave differently on machines with different cultures, so you might want to add `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` as an argument, or use `ParseExact` to avoid flaky behavior. But just changing the underlying data type will avoid this problem in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind some of the work being done on the client side you could do something like this:

```
using (dbEntities entities = new dbEntities())
{
    var db = entities.db_table
    .GroupBy(x => x.ID) //grouping by the id
    .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => 
                 y.REVISIONID).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
   return db.OrderBy(e => DateTime.Parse(e.Date_String)).ToList(); 
}
```

The parsing of the DateTime needs to be modified so it matches the format in the database, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: Did you mean "some of the work being done client side"? I would suggest `AsEnumerable` over `ToList`.

Comment: Of course. I am currently living in a web app world, so in my view it goes: client -> server -> database. But your right :)