# Get error when Convert string to datetime in C#

Tags: c#

How to convert string: `"14/07/2018 14:00:00 ق.ظ"` to `datetime` ?

I am using `Convert.ToDateTime()` and

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("14/07/2018 14:00:00 ق.ظ", 
    "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I got an exception

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Your second argument must match the string with the date to parse, it's obviously  not the case here. Add the missing part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `DateTime.ParseExact` second parameter format need to match exactly as per string you are passing.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("14/07/2018 14:00:00 ق.ظ", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss ق.ظ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want only date part then add `.Date` at the end as below.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("14/07/2018 14:00:00 ق.ظ", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss ق.ظ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date;
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iujVDg)

Comment: I think it is a nice solution if you want everything

Comment: If you want only date then just add `.Date` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

A quick and dirty solution would be to clean the date ahead. Something like this would work:

```
var date = "14/07/2018 14:00:00 ق.ظ";
DateTime dt=DateTime.ParseExact(date.Remove(date.IndexOf(" ")), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dt.Day);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Month);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Year);
```

Output

```
14
7
2018
```

[Try it online!](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hsol20)