# How to work with date in Unity c#?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I create a game in unity. And I add a 'buy subscribe' (apple).

After click buy, I get Date (for example: **08/02/2018 07:24:23**) 08 - is month, 02 - is date.

I get a date through this code:
**productReceipt.subscriptionExpirationDate**

Now i need to do a check, if CurrentDay - 08/02/2018 07:24:23 = 15 days;

How to calculate 2 dates?

Comment: Covert string to datetime and caculate . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using DateTime function. [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) function allows you to calculate the number of days. You just need to get current datetime  & parse your string to datetime format. Here is the code.

```
DateTime dateCurrent = DateTime.Now;
DateTime dateNext = DateTime.Parse(date);
int days = (dateNext - dateCurrent).Days;
```

---

Update:
You can also use TotalDays function to give the remaining time in fraction also. TotalDays is double so remember to change the days to double when using it.