# How to convert this string "14012019" to Datetime

Tags: c#

I want compare the date by first converting the string "14012019" to Datetime

This is the code that I have tried

`DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse("14012019")`;

and

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("14012019", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

and

```
Convert.ToDateTime("14012019")
```

This is the error I'm getting String was not recognized as a valid DateTime Exception.

Comment: Have a closer look at the date string, and think about where the various components are

Comment: You are almost there. [DateTime.ParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) is exactly what you need

Comment: `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("14012019", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: You should try to understand what the `yyyy`,`MM`,`dd`,`HH`,`mm`,`ss` actually mean. If you don't understand it you will never be able to solve such tasks yourself. Read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("14012019", "yyyyMMddHHmmss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Needs to be

```
 DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("14012019", "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Your order of month / day / year was wrong in the method `.ParseExact()`