# Date format problem in C#? While retrieving data from Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

Below is the image of my code please have a look on it.

I am trying to retrieve data from excel sheet and storing it into database table through SQL bulkcopy.

Error:

The date format is `05-01-2019`; it is inserted as `2019-05-01` (database) incorrectly - correct date is `2019-01-05`.

When date is greater than 12 it stores in correct format.

```
2019-12-25 (database) correct 
Excel : 25-12-2019
```

[image]

Comment: You've not posted an image, however, before you do, **don't**. Images of data, code, etc, use all but useless to the volunteers you're asking help from. Post data/code as what is it: `text`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert your string to a date first with

```
DateTime.ParseExact("25-12-1986", "dd-MM-yyyy", NULL)
```

then format it into your date

you can also consider TryParseExact to check for wrong format

your problem is that 05-01-2019 tends to mean 'May 1st 2019' in US style date formats, therefore you need to be very careful with formats.  The policy of automatically making 25-12-1966 into 25th December (which is all it could be interpreted as) is not as helpful as it seems.