# Unable to convert String to Date Time

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

How do I convert string to date time? I am getting "2019-06-07T02" as string. I want to format string to date like below examples

Ex: 2019-06-07T02  -- Friday January 07,2019 2:00 AM

Ex: 2019-06-07T14  --- Friday January 07,2019 2:00 PM

Comment: Show. Code. Please. At least show your research so far.

Comment: You have two problems. Problem 1 - how to `ParseExact` a `string` to a `datetime`. Problem 2 - how to `ToString` from a `datetime` to a `string`.

Comment: Look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime
And

Comment: Why down vote to my question . Is something wrong, pls. let me know will improve. but i see already 2 people answered and also up votes for answers.

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS - The reason for the down-vote is that this kind of question is asked again and again on SO. When you asked your question you would have been prompted with many duplicates - and they should have been sufficient for you to answer your own question before you posted. SO attempts to eliminate all duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

```
var input = "2019-06-07T14";
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var output = datetime.ToString("dddd MMMM dd, yyyy h':'mm tt");
```

This does exactly what you need. (Source [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings))

Edit: I know it might be too manual but if you want to configure it more, this way you can, if not, go with oleksa's answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "2019-06-07T02";
var dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyy-MM-ddThh", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var longstr = dt.ToLongDateString() + dt.ToLongTimeString();
```

please note that `ToLongDateString` and `ToLongTimeString` depends on windows user regional settings

[the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)