# VB.net yyyymmdd format needs to parse as date

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

I have a string in `yyyymmdd` format and need to pass that to a function which date type. I have also listed the definition of `GetCP` function

```
Dim sp As String() = fName.Split(".")
Dim  fdate As string = sp.Substring(0,8)
Dim dt As String  = fDate
Library.GetCP(dt)  '' getting an error here as the not the right format.
```

```
Friend Shared Function GetCP(ByVal TDate As Date) As String
```

Comment: Try converting your `String` to a `Date` before passing it.  [Here is a post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/919244/5162073) showing how to do that.

Comment: It's not that its the wrong format but it's the wrong type. A `System.String` is not a `System.DateTime`. If your input is `string` then you must convert it to a `System.DateTime` and pass that to your method call as that is the expected input type.