# How to convert 1 Jan to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a `string` value of `1 Jan` which indicates a date for batch program to run based on the date.

May I know if there is quick method to convert `1 Jan` to a `DateTime` value which I can use to compare if it is today?

Otherwise, I guess `substring` and `replace` of characters may be the only alternative I can think of.

Thank you

Comment: How can `1 Jan` also be `10 Jan` ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say it could also be double digit day, which I would need to handle.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZZbG9g - seems pretty straight forward? did you try?

Comment: so you mean `01 Jan` and `1 Jan`, don´t you?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes you are correct. however the user input will be `1 Jan` instead of `01 Jan`

Comment: So how does `01 Jan` come into play at all?

Comment: @HimBromBeere let me remove it to avoid confusion. I had `substring` in mind and I thought it would affect so thought I should bring it up.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - he just wanted to give an example of a day past the 9th day of the month, he could have also given the example of `15 Jan`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime) There are a lot of other duplicates

Comment: though not related to the question, you might consider using cron expressions to manage schedules, which way you don't have to run into issues, if there is an input of 29 Feb, we cannot run it next year on till leap year right, these are some cases worth considering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `ParseExact`

```
var mydate = DateTime.ParseExact("1 Jan 2020", "d MMM yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

OR

```
var mydate = DateTime.ParseExact("1 Jan", "d MMM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "1 Jan";
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime tempDate = Convert.ToDateTime(date, culture);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.