# How to Convert long string to DateTime?

Tags: c#

I have a date string in the following format:

```
var dateString = Fri Jun 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
```

How can I convert this to a DateTime in C# such as 26/06/2020 00:00:00

I have tried:

```
  DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

And:
DateTime.ParseExact(dateString);

And I get:

```
 System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'
```

Comment: Note that a `DateTime` does not have a format. It is a `struct` with fields for Year, Month, Day, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: You need to use DateTime.ParseExact with the format you have. You could read more about formats in the link provided in the comments to answer

Comment: No, I get: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: You can try this format: `"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(British Summer Time)'"` Unfortunately there is no format specifier for using the thing in the parenthesis to detect time zone or similar, so you can't generalize this to handle `(... whatever ...)`

Comment: Read those answers again. The highest-voted answer says to use `ParseExact`, not `Parse`. And you must provide a format that matches the format you are using. The format strings are easily searched for on learn.microsoft.com, but I happen to have them bookmarked: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using `DateTime.ParseExact` and providing a custom date time format. However, this will only work if you first modify the input string to be able to fit the [custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) that are included in .net.

```cs
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

var input = "Fri Jun 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)";

// set up a regex that will match the text starting with GMT, and extract just the timezone offset 
// (the description of the timezone is irrelevant here)
var r = new Regex(@"GMT([+-]\d\d\d\d) \([\w\s]*\)");

// this will remove the extra text: "Fri Jun 26 2020 00:00:00 +0100"
// now we can match it in our format string
var s = r.Replace(input, "$1");

var f = "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz"; // matches the s variable
var d = DateTime.ParseExact(s, f, provider); // you now have parsed your date
```

This will include the timezone offset in the `DateTime` object. If you just want it to be set to "26/06/2020 00:00:00" and to ignore the datetime offset, then just change the regex replace above to replace with `String.Empty` instead of `$1`.

Comment: I think this is almost there. My date shows as Wed Jun 24 2020 00:00:00+0100 but still a format exception

Comment: That is a different format than what you had in the question. To handle that, the `GMT` needs to be removed from the regex and the end of the format string should be `hh:mm:sszzz` (since you lost the space there).

Comment: This is the format after running it through the regex you provided

Comment: Try it now please

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem.

`var dateString = "Fri Jun 26 2020 00:00:00 GMT + 0100(British Summer Time)"; Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(dateString.Substring(4, 11)));`

Answer (score -2):

Hello so what you can do is you can take advantage of "datetime" class and just write this:

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
```

edit: sorry i forgot to supply the link haha
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1

Comment: This is not an answer for the given question

Comment: He did, but the answer initially was "how to convert given string to C# DateTime" :)

Comment: yes and if you read https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1 you should liturally get an anwser :)

Comment: removed my downvote because last link could be partially helpful for the questioner

Comment: ikr i kinda forgot to supply it in the post gonna edit rn..

Comment: I get the same error:  System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Comment: Note that you can and should alter your answer to match the fully flushed out question. The original revision of the question did not contain enough information to answer with anything other than a guess.