# Conversion failed with "date" was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-conversion

I try convert the date with below code,

```
string currDate = @"Fri, 10 Jul 2020 05:48:28 -0500 (CDT)";
DateTime convDate = Convert.ToDateTime(currDate);

Console.WriteLine("COnverted Date :: " + convDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

But, it failed with below error message,

```
  Unhandled exception. System.FormatException: String 'Fri, 10 Jul 2020 05:48:28 -0500 (CDT)' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

It would be nice anyone help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParseExact`

Comment: Ya.. Thanks for your response. I tried with this DateTime convDate = DateTime.ParseExact(currDate, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);. But, still the same error.

Comment: The pattern does not match. That's all. Try to Format a date with that pattern. you will find it will look totally different.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: Try string `Fri, 10 Jul 2020 05:48:28 -05:00` without (CDT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put the `(CDT)` into single quotes in format string to ignore it while parsing using [`DateTime.ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ParseExact_System_String_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_) method

```cs
string currDate = @"Fri, 10 Jul 2020 05:48:28 -0500 (CDT)";
DateTime convDate = DateTime.ParseExact(currDate, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss K '(CDT)'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It returns you a local date time, in my end output is

> Converted Date :: 2020-07-10T13:48:28.000+03:00

To get the UTC one you can pass `DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal` parameter to `ParseExact` method. It gives you

> Converted Date :: 2020-07-10T10:48:28.000Z

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Actually, I got this date format from google email. So, i receive different format every time. For example, sometime I got the date like this, Tue, 26 May 2020 11:15:19 GMT

Comment: @Ramachandran For GMT time you can use `ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'` format string. If you have a different format every time, you might remove the timezone prefix from string first, then parse it

Comment: Ya... Thank you.. Thanks for your help.