# how to search datetime in web api url? web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

i want to know how to search datetime in url of web api, i want to search the date and it can show with xml format in website. such as if i search 2018-01-01 and it will show after 2018-01-01 date and equals to 2018-01-01. do i need to parse datetime to string first? Is this possible to do it?

my code:

```
        [HttpGet()]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            List<TestClass> test = new List<TestClass>();
            string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
            string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Access, Date From tbluser";
            sqlconn.Open();
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Test.Add(new TestClass()
                    {
                        UserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0)),
                        Name = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                        Mobile = reader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                        Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3)),
                        Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(4))
                    });
                }
            return Ok(test);
        }
```

my class:

```
[DataContract]
public class TestClass
    {
        [DataMember(Order=1)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public int Age { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

expected:

```
http://localhost:IP/api/value?Date=2018-01-01
```

expected result:

```
<ArrayOfTest xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Test>
<UserId>1</UserId>
<Name>Emily</Name>
<Mobile>8375269</Mobile>
<Age>21</Age>
<Date>2018-01-01</Date>
</Test>
<Test>
<UserId>2</UserId>
<Name>Victor</Name>
<Mobile>08314732</Mobile>
<Age>31</Age>
<Date>2022-03-05</Date>
</Test>
<Test>
<UserId>3</UserId>
<Name>Peter</Name>
<Mobile>32475962</Mobile>
<Age>45</Age>
<Date>2019-10-25</Date>
</Test>
<Test>
<UserId>4</UserId>
<Name>John</Name>
<Mobile>24398592</Mobile>
<Age>24</Age>
<Date>2018-02-16</Date>
</Test>
<Test>
<UserId>5</UserId>
<Name>Kobe</Name>
<Mobile>19873491</Mobile>
<Age>38</Age>
<Date>2020-05-12</Date>
</Test>
```

Comment: Are you looking for string to dateTime conversion ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/919249/8763644

Comment: not really, what i want is to convert datetime in the database to string and do like a keyword search in the url link to find out datetime in web api

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the date as a String and then Convert it into Date format
I think it's work

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string Date)
    {
        List<TestClass> test = new List<TestClass>();

        DateTime? DateInFormat = Date.ToDate("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconn"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);
        string sqlquery = "SELECT UserID, Name, Mobile, Access, Date From tbluser where Date ="+DateInFormat+"";
        sqlconn.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Test.Add(new TestClass()
            {
                UserId = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0)),
                Name = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                Mobile = reader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                Age = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(3)),
                Date = Convert.ToDateTime(reader.GetValue(4))
            });
        }
        return Ok(test);
    }
```

Comment: `DateTime? DateInFormat = Date.ToDate("yyyy-MM-dd");` i got a red underline on `ToDate`, and it said "" 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToDate' and no extension method 'ToDate' accepting a first agrument of type 'string' could be found.

Comment: Did you use System namespaces for date?

Comment: Or Don't need to typecast string to date just pass the date string in the SQL statement.

Comment: so i just pass the date with sql statment only, i don't need this syntax`DateTime? DateInFormat = Date.ToDate("yyyy-MM-dd");`?

Comment: Yes, Just pass the date string

Comment: it show this `The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'Date' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult Get(System.DateTime)' in 'Testing.Controllers.apiController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional`

Comment: Did you pass any string when you call this api

Comment: How you call This api? With Postman?

Comment: what is pass any string?

Comment: with google chrome

Comment: You should use Postman for testing api

Comment: Or when you request any api with Ajax so you need to pass a value (If api ask for it)

Comment: but this api will use on my project system for get data from database, do i still test on Postman?

Comment: No postman is not necessary but pass a value when you request for api

Comment: how to don't get the error?

Comment: It's Up to You, your logic makes your code perfect.